# What is the difference between packet and payload

Tags: packet, payload, ipsec

I got this defitiniton below is it true and what is the difference between packet and payload?

The ESP (Encapsulation Security Payload) protocol is a member of IPSec suite. Its
    purpose is to guarantee payload's (message) integrity, data origin authentication of IP
    packets and confidentially of the payload.
    It does provide protection for the entire packet, not only to the payload.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14737098/8740349); A payload is the part of the packet with the actual info (the good stuff!) There are other parts of a packet, the packet headers, that describe the payload, like how big it is.

**But for ESP, actual answer is:**

It depends on the mode.

In tunnel mode ESP secures whole packet, in transport mode ESP secures **only** payload.

Answer (score 3):

A payload is the part of the packet with the actual info (the good stuff!) There are other parts of a packet, the packet headers, that describe the payload, like how big it is.

The description is telling you that protection is provided for everything in the packet, including it's headers. Hope that helps!

Comment: I asked some people and they said this sentence is false, but it seems it is true. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if this sentence is true?  ESP seucres maybe only payload? Cause in materials it is said that this sentence is wrong, but don't know why.

Comment: It depends on how it's being used. See the "Two ways of using ESP" section on this page: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzaja%2Frzajaesp.htm